# Why is it passing a param when it should not - Laravel Routing

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

Bizarre issue, lets see some routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/races', ['as' => 'races.list', 'uses' => 'RacesController@index']);
Route::get('/admin/races/{race}', ['as' => 'races.race', 'uses' => 'RacesController@show']);
Route::get('/admin/races/create', ['as' => 'races.create', 'uses' => 'RacesController@create']);
Route::get('/admin/races/{race}/edit', ['as' => 'races.edit', 'uses' => 'RacesController@edit']);
```

Seems normal enough, lets see the controller:

```
class RacesController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return view('admin.races.list');
    }

    public function show(GameRace $race) {
        return view('admin.races.race', [
            'race' => $race,
        ]);
    }

    public function create() {
        return view('admin.races.manage', [
            'race' => null,
        ]);
    }

    public function edit(GameRace $race) {
        return view('admin.races.manage', [
            'race' => $race,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Seems normal enough. The issue is:

When I go to `/admin/races/create` I get a 404. The reason being is because, exception:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException^ {#851
  #model: "App\Flare\Models\GameRace"
  #ids: array:1 [
    0 => "create"
  ]
  #message: "No query results for model [App\Flare\Models\GameRace] new"
  #code: 0
  #file: "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ImplicitRouteBinding.php"
  #line: 47
  trace: {
   .....
```

Why is calling:

```
<li><a href="{{route('races.create')}}">Create Race</a></li>
```

Causing Laravel to take the word `create` and inject it in as a model? No other route that I have, that is similar does this. For context, here's how we create items:

```
Route::get('/admin/items/create', ['as' => 'items.create', 'uses' => 'ItemsController@create']);
```

Same concept, just instead of races its items. So how laravel messing this up?

I have run all the cache clears and route clears and everything. Same issue. Even tests are failing on this. No where am I calling this with a param (especially not one called create) so it should not be assuming there is a param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have defined `Route::get('/admin/races/{race}' ..` first, so it'll hit that route regardless of what the value is. Simply moving the `create` route before the `show` route will solve your problem.

```php
Route::get('/admin/races', ['as' => 'races.list', 'uses' => 'RacesController@index']);
Route::get('/admin/races/create', ['as' => 'races.create', 'uses' => 'RacesController@create']);
Route::get('/admin/races/{race}', ['as' => 'races.race', 'uses' => 'RacesController@show']);
Route::get('/admin/races/{race}/edit', ['as' => 'races.edit', 'uses' => 'RacesController@edit']);
```

That said, you can simplify this a lot more with a simple resource-route.

```php
Route::resource('/admin/races', ['as' => 'races.list', 'uses' => 'RacesController'])->only("index", "show", "create", "edit");
```

Comment: 6 minutes till I can accept! As for your last point, I never knew that. Thank you good person!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to the accepted answer is to specify conditions for the parameter in the parametrised route. For example if `{race}` needs to be numeric you can do:

```
Route::get('/admin/races', ['as' => 'races.list', 'uses' => 'RacesController@index']);
Route::get('/admin/races/{race}', ['as' => 'races.race', 'uses' => 'RacesController@show'])->where('race', '\d+');
Route::get('/admin/races/create', ['as' => 'races.create', 'uses' => 'RacesController@create']);
Route::get('/admin/races/{race}/edit', ['as' => 'races.edit', 'uses' => 'RacesController@edit']);
```

This is useful in the cases where you can't control the order of the routes (e.g. there's a package registering routes that conflict).